# Modulo code golf

Tags: code-golf, math

Write a function `f(a,b)` that returns `a mod b` given the constraints:

- you can't use division in any way
- `f(a,b)` is always positive, eg: `f(-1,5) = 4`
- it performs reasonably well for values of ~`10e50` for `a` and `b`

Comment: If division is disallowed, it WILL perform badly,because only repeated subtraction is left.

Comment: Subtraction is not so bad but you also have multiplication.

Comment: Can the second operand be negative as well?

Comment: @sepp2k: It's not a requirement so treat it as it suits you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Haskell <s>36</s> 35 (<s>34?</s> 33)

If I may call the function `?` instead:

```
1234567890123456789012345678901234
a?b|a<0=(a+b)?b|a>b=(a-b)?b|0<1=a
```

Elseway:

```
f a b|a<0=f(a+b)b|a>b=f(a-b)b|0<1=a
```

Comment: Nice idea, but this does not meet the requirements as it does not work at all if `a` is negative (it will just return `a` unchanged).

Comment: @Sepp2k: Now it works.

Comment: Note that `0<1` is shorter than `True`

Comment: Could you try running this with input 10^50, 3? I'm pretty sure it wouldn't complete.

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, 62 bytes

Regex modulo

```
sub f{($a,$b)=@_;$_=1x$a;s/^(1{$b})+(1+)$/return length $2/e;}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Java Solution, <strike>114</strike> 66 chars

Its now 66, thanks sepp2k!~

```
 int m(int x,int y){x=(x<0)?-(x*y-x):x;while(x>=y) x-=y;return x;}
```

Comment: This is 80 character if you remove the unnecessary whitespace. 73 if you also make the method non-static. 66 if you additionally make it package-private.

Comment: [:)] that was easy, thanks!.. I am so used to beautify the code oops!

Comment: I suggested an edit; discard it if you don't like it.

Comment: I dont know, If this is right place to ask this or not.. but I do not know how to strike off  (that must be easy.. idiot aman :P )

Comment: It's 64 by removing the whitespace at the start

Comment: And the whitespace after `while(x>=y)` is unnecessary

Comment: I know it has been 5.5 years, but you can golf it like this `int m(int x,int y){for(x=x<0?-(x*y-x):x;x>=y;x-=y);return x;}` (**61 bytes**)

Answer (score 2):

### Haskell (22)

Abuse of the rules, please don't downvote: Mathematically, the modulus may be arbitrary large, because all moduli are equivalent. Thus, you may also use this, it WILL always return a positive result:

```
1234567890123456789012
a?b|a<0=(a+b)?b|True=a
```

And it will also always satisfy the equation

```
a?b = c <-> n*b + c = a
```

For some integer n.

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby - 72 chars

```
f=->a,b{a==b&&0||a<b&&a+(a<0&&b||0)||(t=b;t<<=1until t>a;f[a-(t>>1),b])}
```

Uses recursion like a Binary Search to find the remainder.

Test

```
p f[106, 95]
p f[23, 2]
p f[-1, 5]
p f[20, 7]
p f[10**100, 3]
p f[4*10**200, 3123123]

11
1
4
6
1
823660
```

Answer (score 2):

### Brainfuck - 37 characters

```
,>,<[->-[>+>>]>[+[-<+>]>+>>]<<<<<]>>.
```

Takes a and b as bytes from standard input. Outputs one byte. Does not meet criteria to work with arbitrary size numbers, but to do so in brainfuck would not be simple.

Comment: I'm torn.  The problem doesn't explicitely ask for arbitrary size integers, which would be a pain to implement in BF, that's for sure.  But you're not even close to performing "well" for e50, since you won't perform it at all.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more I think this is defensible. All you need to make it handle e50 is an implementation that works on arbitrarily large numbers. Those do exist. Then it is just a matter of defining efficiency. Since this performs a whole lot better than brainfuck's built in modulo operator, I say it passes that too.

Comment: I have no issue with the efficiency.  What got me started is that no BF implementation I know of would be able to run your code on anything close to e50.  The easy hurdle is the cell size, but implementations do exist that implement these as bignums.  The hard one is input.  I don't know of a single implementation that returns anything over 255, and can't conceive a reasonable one returning anything over 2^32.  You could always find one and read input over several operations, but your character count doesn't reflect that.  (publishing a new implementation for the the task is frowned upon)

Comment: Fair enough. I was assuming I had an implementation that allows an arbitrarily large bignum input. Failing to find (or be allowed to create) that, this submission probably does not meet the requirements. It definitely can't handle negative input anyways. But it is remarkably competitive in count for a BF program, even if it is not quite there.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 35 bytes

```
f=lambda a,b:a if a<b else f(a-b,b)
```

Sadly, I can't use `and`/`or` short-circuiting here, so I have to do with one more byte.

Comment: This does not perform correctly for negative inputs.

Comment: @Quelklef [It doesn't have to](//codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/866/95115?noredirect=1#comment1493_866). It would have been nice to include negatives as well, since this is ½ trivial as of now, though.

Comment: I think I'm reading this differently than you. Either way, I guess you're right, since there's already an accepted answer

Comment: @Quelklef I read that comment as "you can treat negatives any way", which means that undefined behavior can occur as well.